# How to save uploaded files into a mapped folder

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a desktop application which uploads files to an upload servlet. I want that uploaded files to be saved into a folder outside Tomcat, which is already mapped.

The url for the mapped folder is: "localhost:8080/MyApp/documents".

Physical path for the mapped folder is: /Users/gyo/Documents/MyApp/documents

Probably I'm making a newbie mistake but I would like to know: Is it possible to save the files in the mapped folder? If yes, how can I do that since `servletContext.getRealPath("")` is returning me the full path where the app is deployed?

Comment: Why do you think you need `getRealPath()`? Just use `new File("/Users/gyo/Documents/MyApp/documents", filename)` the usual Java way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that explains how to upload files in Java running on tomcat and spring. Look for permissions on that folder "ls -ltr /folder-path/" to see owner and write permissions.

http://www.gingercart.com/Home/java-snippets/upload-images-java-code-example

Also look at java policies set on Tomcat for file/folder permissions at $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy